# I can't get the apk flutter when I throw my phone does not work. Is there an error in my code?

Tags: flutter

I can't get the apk flutter android phone when I throw it does not work. I think my code is correct. can you tell me my mistake?
apk 32 and 64 bit separately
 I build but did not work

I can't get the apk flutter android phone when I throw it does not work. I think my code is correct. can you tell me my mistake?
apk 32 and 64 bit separately
 I build but did not work

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }




android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.hyuni"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1 
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk{ abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' }
    }
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Do you use Firebase? And you can share "pubspec.yaml" file with us?

Comment: I dont use firebase. Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize device configurations or manage it yourself with multiple APKs gives the error.

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_tableview: ^1.0.1
  flutter_pdfview:
  path_provider:
  http:
  video_player:
  url_launcher: ^5.1.2
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0
  splashscreen:
  flutter_rating: ^0.0.2  
  logger: 0.7.0+2
  open_file: 2.0.3